# While não está carregando os registros

Tags: mysqli, while

Estou tentando repetir uma região porém, apesar do mysqli_num_rows indicar que tem 9 registros, no while não está vindo nada. Meu código está assim:

```
        $qry = "SELECT 
        pe_orclinhas.id_orclinha, 
        pe_orcgrupos.grupo_orcamento, 
        pe_orclinhas.dc, 
        pe_orclinhas.orclinha
        FROM pe_orcgrupos 
        INNER JOIN pe_orclinhas ON pe_orcgrupos.id_orca = pe_orclinhas.orcgrupo
        WHERE id_orclinha = $linhab";
        $consulta   = mysqli_query($MySQLi,$qry);
        $registros  = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

        while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

        $grp        = $registro[0];
        $tp         = $registro[1];
        $descr      = $registro[2];

    ?>
    <br />
    <em style='color: #003300;'><?php echo $grp; ?></em>
   <?php
   } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de números, digite o nome da coluna dentro do índice das arrays:

```
while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

    $grp        = $registro['ColunaA'];
    $tp         = $registro['ColunaB'];
    $descr      = $registro['ColunaC'];

?>
<br />
<em style='color: #003300;'><?php echo $grp; ?></em>
```

Answer (score 0):

Experimente:

```
 <?php
    $qry = "SELECT 
    pe_orclinhas.id_orclinha, 
    pe_orcgrupos.grupo_orcamento, 
    pe_orclinhas.dc, 
    pe_orclinhas.orclinha
    FROM pe_orcgrupos 
    INNER JOIN pe_orclinhas ON pe_orcgrupos.id_orca = pe_orclinhas.orcgrupo
    WHERE id_orclinha = $linhab";
    $consulta   = mysqli_query($MySQLi,$qry);
    $registros  = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

    while($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

      $grp        = $registro[0];
      $tp         = $registro[1];
      $descr      = $registro[2];

      echo "<br />"
      echo "<em style='color: #003300;'><" . $grp . "></em>"

    } ?>
```